# Non-Sequitur Questions: how to handle them

Tags: discussion, on-topic

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35161/if-sun-comes-up-in-west-and-earth-starts-spinning-in-opossite-way-could-gravity) popped up a few minutes ago and its premise has no foundational basis in anything.

No really.  "If the Earth were to spin the other way, could gravity exist?"

This is such a complete non-sequitur, so I am unsure how to handle it.  None of the flagging or closing options seem to apply here (beyond "other"), yet it seems to me that this question is...not appropriate for Worldbuilding.  It's not a bad question though (aside from the poor English due to non-native speaker, on the surface the question is fine), it's just that it is blatantly *wrong.*

Aside from down-voting and commenting, how should such a question be handled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it can be answered, answer it.

If it cannot, then close it (with a custom close reason if appropriate).

Optionally, down vote if you feel it's a poor question.

Move on :)

Note that in this case the question actually has quite a good answer. Even poor questions can lead to good answers.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  It was just so far out of left field I was just confused.

Comment: Yes, sometimes you do come across questions that make you go :o

Answer (score 4):

I came accros the question in the review queue. I don't think there were grounds to actually close it: it is on-topic, it is answerable, etc. It is just wrong, so downvote it. You might want to give the OP a chance by commenting first and downvoting later.