# Scope clarification discussions

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Different subjects are being discussed for a clarification or a re-definition of the scope of the site. We want to have clear lines to separate the questions that are accepted on worldbuilding from those that aren't.

However, due to different people starting different approaches, it can be confusing to find all of them and follow the complete discussion. The intention of this part is to accumulate links for the different parts of the discussion for clarification.

Comment: Let's make sure all of these are tagged [meta-tag:on-topic].

Comment: @MonicaCellio, Just checked all of them right now. A few weren't...

Answer (score 6):

Below are summarised the different discussions on meta about the clarification of the scope of the site. Please only include generic discussions and not threads about a single question. Furthermore, since we want to consider the current discussion, try to keep only recent threads in.

---

#### Case Studies

Where some highly voted questions are presented by some users and discussed to see whether they do or do not fit the scope of the site.

[Case Study Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3048/case-study-series)

1. Tim B's [Case Studies - on or off topic?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/case-studies-on-or-off-topic)
2. [Case Study #2 - Daaaah Whoosh](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/case-study-2-daaaah-whoosh)
3. [Case Study #3 - James](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3093/case-study-3-james)
4. [Case Study #4 - overactor](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3145/case-study-4-overactor)
5. [Case Studies - Green's Highest Viewed Questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/case-studies-greens-highest-viewed-questions)
6. [Case Study #6 - HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3200/case-study-6-hde-226868?lq=1)
7. [Case Study #7 - Aify](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3225/case-study-7-aify)
8. [Case study - Pavel Janicek](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/case-study-pavel-janicek)
9. [Case Study: Monica Cellio](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3261/case-study-monica-cellio)

---

#### Risk Factors

Where we intend to define some factors which makes some risks for the question to be out of scope.

[Worldbuilding Scope - Risk Factors](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3206/worldbuilding-scope-risk-factors)

1. [Risk Factor definition: Too Individual/Character Based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3229/risk-factor-definition-too-individual-character-based)
2. [Risk Factor Definition: Too Story Based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/risk-factor-definition-too-story-based)
3. [Risk Factor Definition: Multiple Questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3312/risk-factor-definition-multiple-questions)
4. [Risk Factor Definition: Too Vague](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3365/risk-factor-definition-too-vague)

---

#### What Ifs

Many questions seems to follow a "what if" pattern and a few discussions started from that observation.

- [Is Worldbuilding a What If Site?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/is-worldbuilding-a-what-if-site)
- [Is Worldbuilding a What if Site - a followup](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/is-worldbuilding-a-what-if-site-a-followup?lq=1)
- [What if there were a What If?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3124/what-if-there-were-a-what-if)
- [Sample questions for WhatIf](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3137/sample-questions-for-whatif?lq=1)
- [What if Worldbuilding banned What If questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3193/what-if-worldbuilding-banned-what-if-questions?lq=1)

---

#### Story-based

- [When should I close a question as "Too Story Based"?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/when-should-i-close-a-question-as-too-story-based)
- [Why is my question "Too Story Based" and how do I get it opened?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened)
- [Story vs World building: study case](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3318/story-vs-world-building-study-case)
- [Are Too Character Based and Too Plot Based the same?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3277/are-too-character-based-and-too-plot-based-the-same)

---

#### Miscellaneous

- [Non-Sequitur Questions: how to handle them](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/non-sequitur-questions-how-to-handle-them)
- [Should we answer off-topic questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/should-we-answer-off-topic-questions)
- [Please clarify "Elements of Plot" to be more concise](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3133/please-clarify-elements-of-plot-to-be-more-concise)
- [Are questions based on movies okay?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3141/are-questions-based-on-movies-okay)
- [What happened to the idea generation close reason?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3304/what-happened-to-the-idea-generation-close-reason)
- [What the scope of Worldbuilding is NOT about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3208/what-the-scope-of-worldbuilding-is-not-about)

---

#### Taking action

- [Why was my question closed? [Collected Answers]](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3363/why-was-my-question-closed)
- [Should we answer off-topic questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/should-we-answer-off-topic-questions)
- [Rules of Peer Moderation](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3366/rules-of-peer-moderation)