# When should I close a question as "Too Story Based"?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, close-reasons

See also: [Why is my question "Too Story Based" and how do I get it opened?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3300/49)

What criteria should I use when closing a question as Too Story Based?

Answer (score 7):

A question should be closed if it contains any of the following:

1. Asking about what a character or small group of characters would decide in a given situation
2. Asking about a specific individual
3. Not asking about building the world but instead creating a scenario
4. Lack of context, if it is unclear how the question relates to building a world

It should not be closed for any of these things (unless it also has the things above):

5. Asking about what options are available in a given situation (if insufficiently constrained close as too broad).
6. Similarly asking for techniques or strategies can be on topic (if insufficiently constrained close as too broad).
7. Creating significant figures such as leaders, gods in a pantheon, historical figures, etc where the question relates to building of the world.
8. Asking about the reaction of an organisation or country significant enough to be considered party of the world in a situation where that reaction can reasonably be predicted.