# Question closed as dupe when it isn’t

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just recently asked the following question:

> [In a world without humans—or any caretakers—would domestic house pets simply regress into being feral or die?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/123389/in-a-world-without-humans-or-any-caretakers-would-domestic-house-pets-simply-reg)

Which has been closed as a duplicate of this other question:

> [Which livestock could survive without humans?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/117574/which-livestock-could-survive-without-humans)

My question is clearly about domesticated *pets* and not about farm animals and livestock. Two completely different populations of animals.

As [kingledion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/23519/kingledion) states [in the comments](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/123389/in-a-world-without-humans-or-any-caretakers-would-domestic-house-pets-simply-reg/123397?noredirect=1#comment381546_123389):

> “@JakeGould Looks good on edit. I don't see this as a duplicate any more.”

Yet… Boom! Question closed.

So I believe the question was unfairly closed by [SRM](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/26246/srm), [Mike Scott](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/220/mike-scott), [MichaelK](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/12297/michaelk), [Renan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21222/renan), [CaM](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/32987/cam) so I am requesting the question be re-opened.

Comment: None of the close voters explained why they decided to close the question. I just voted to reopen.

Comment: Couple things here.  1.  This question got a lot of flak pretty quick.  Users should remember to [Be nice](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct)
2.  Jake, the word domesticated is commonly used to refer to livestock, so that people were confused or asked for clarification is not crazy or unreasonable. 3.  All in all the process worked the way it should have, but it seems everyone could have been a bit more polite.  So.  Yeah.  We're good.  Question is reopened.

Comment: @James Fine. Then let it stand here like the main question and answer thread. Won’t chose an answer on either and let them sit as-is. Enjoy!

Comment: It looks to me like your question picked up three close votes before it was edited. That is fine! The edit fixed it, and as @James said, that is how the process works. Even had you not come to post here, your question would likely have been reopened once it got that clarifying edit. Please keep in mind, this is not a chat room. Questions are edited to clarity and answered on a timescale of days, not minutes. As you participate here more, please be patient with the review process.

Answer (score 9):

You can edit your question and politely explain why the proposed duplicate does not cover what you are asking.

Immediately after your question will enter the reopen queue, and community members will decide if it can be reopened or not.

Alternatively, other members can simply vote to reopen the question, and again it will enter the reopen queue.

If the reopening gets enough approval votes, the question will be reopened.

Answer (score 4):

First, please remember that [closing a question is an opportunity, not a judgment](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se).  Just because the other question was about livestock doesn't mean the answers didn't apply to your question.

In other words, it's an opportunity for you to review the other question and use that knowledge to improve your own.  Frankly, your response suggests you reviewed it with as little depth and consideration that you believe the close voters did to you.  However, the answer from Marshall Tigerus applies to your question.

**What should you have done?**

You had an opportunity to improve and clarify your question and explain why those answers were insufficient.

**Why is this important?**

It improves the quality of the site as a whole by reducing clutter in the SE universe.  Stack Exchange is ***NOT*** a place where individuals come to receive individual answers.  It is a community where people join together to create an encyclopedic reference that many *other people* can also use and enjoy.

You were not the only person the close voters were thinking about.  From the SE perspective, we WANT to point similar questions to previously asked questions that have suitable answers.  Not only does it remove the clutter of many similar answers, but it gives future users the chance to see their question from multiple points of view, which is highly beneficial.

**However...**

While Marshall's answer is (IMO) a perfectly sensible answer to your question (it's as valid for small animals as it is large), you were specific with your question.  It's likely too broad (dogs and cats, for example, have different survival traits compared to lizards and snakes, which are more outdoor-habitat-dependent), but I'll vote to reopen it.

However, I'm also going to downvote it for lack of research.  It appears some of your answer could have been found simply by reading [wikipedia's entry for "feral"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feral).  The research would have (IMO) resulted in a narrower question or series of questions that would have resulted in higher quality answers.