# See Proposal for Editing Rules

Tags: discussion

Go here: [Proposal for Editing Rules](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8038/proposal-for-editing-rules)

Note to L. Dutch: do nòt roll back and do not "protect" this question. This question should be closed. All further answers or comments should be referred to the linked question.

Comment: This might be a bit too big of a bite. If well written, it would entirely replace one ore more pages of the [help]. I can think of quite literally two dozen Meta pages this would need to link to immediately. You sure you don't want to focus on just the etiquette of editing?

Comment: I'm just afraid of it being overwhelming to the few people who actively participate in Meta. [I'd love to see a comprehensive final statement](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388/40609), but my own experience is that people generally only have the time or the attention span to swallow so much. My recommendation would be to start on [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask] and determine the top 3-5 issues that aren't well addressed (like editing), then ask one question at a time. But, I'll follow wherever you lead, Yoda!

Comment: After the last edit this questions is a straight duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't get the purpose of this question.

Just make more confusion by duplicating content already available in different location and make it even worse when one gets updated and the other lags behind?

Each and every of the point has already a page explaining it, and if some users are not putting the effort of finding, reading and understanding them, why would another post lost in the queue make any difference?