# Why was "Zombies Versus Skeletons: Optimal Strategies?" closed?

Tags: support, on-topic, specific-question

I had [asked the question titled *Zombies Versus Skeletons: Optimal Strategies?*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/45444/zombies-versus-skeletons-optimal-strategies) a couple weeks ago about what might happen given my two armies with their various powers clashing. It was closed a couple days later for being off-topic and too story based.

When the question was still in the "on hold" phase, I had edited my question with a note at the bottom, asking those who voted to close it why, if, according to [this post,](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened) "capabilities of characters...are on-topic, but questions must focus on what is possible or likely to develop, not what someone would or should do."

Am I missing something, or are the older guys around here just trying to keep newbies like me from posting questions?

Comment: Please keep in mind that many questions which are a poor fit for the question-and-answers format can be discussed in [chat].

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the possibilities are endless and there's no way of saying which of two equally well written but contradictory answers is correct.

For close reasons you could go with either of: too broad, opinion based

As a concept it seems interesting and good fun, but as a question we wouldn't be able to give you a good answer.

Comment: I understand all of that, but then why did they close it for being "too story based"?

Comment: @DonielFilreis, You've given us a whole world to play in, an answer would be a story, any outcome depends on intelligent (or otherwise) actions by a series of protagonists. e.g. the zombie that got into the hen shed (up to 16,000 hens in a shed) or a sheep farm.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there Doniel and welcome to the site.

Us *old guys* always want the site to have more questions.  More questions means more people and a livelier site.

That said **not all questions fit the format of the site**, which is not to say they are not interesting/good questions.  In your case the scenario is interesting but there are simply not enough constraints on the question to make any two answers objectively comparable which is when things get too broad and/or too opinion based.

There are a couple options available to help you hone your question before posting it on the main site.  You can post the question in the sandbox on meta or feel free to visit us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilders-general-chat) to get some feedback.

I can assure you that none of the old guys want to chase you away from the site though I admit some are a bit more tactful and helpful than others.

I hope you stick around and enjoy worldbuilding, its a crazy place.