# Why is "Minimum nuclear weapons required for deterrent" off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, close-reasons

This question has been closed, the reason given is that it is off-topic and "too story based".

[Minimum nuclear weapons required for deterrent?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/104779/minimum-nuclear-weapons-required-for-deterrent)

The meta question cited to justify this is as follows:

[Why is my question "Too Story Based" and how do I get it opened?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened)

However... I don't understand why this is off-topic if the cited logic from meta is:

> "only the person who is developing a plotline can decide how
>   characters will act or the plots will develop"

This is clearly more objective. There's multiple ways to answer it, and a lot of material which can be cited to justify this. In fact many comments and answers already have provided evidence to back their arguments.

> "Capabilities of characters within a world...are on-topic, but
>   questions must focus on what is possible-"

To me, the question seems perfectly within this logic, as it asks for capabilities about what is possible.  I do not understand how this could be misconstrue to be about whether a nation should use their deterrent or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

The question was quite fine for me.

Anyhow, from my limited understanding of the process, I think you could just rephrase the question along the lines of

> In a fictional world that looks like ours, but where superpowers are
>   not meddling too much in the affairs of other countries, there is a
>   country that wishes to invest in a nuclear weapon deterrent, but it
>   does not want to overspend because it is mostly farmland: how many
>   bombs should it build?

This should sound more like worldbuilding for the stricter among the reviewers.

I hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for suggesting fictional world where this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't vote on this one, but  you are  asking   about real world countries sand real world  weapons. No room for fiction, your world is already  built: ours. And if world is already set and built, is it hard to see why people think it is not worldbuilding?

Capabilities of characters within a world are on-topic - but this case is when new capabilities are added to a world. Add ability to see future to some characters and you have different world. Take weapons that are produced and you have the very same world.

Comment: Interesting, I've seen some questions about alternative history which basically take a historical moment in time and ask "is this possible?" so I didn't see how my question was any different to those sorts of questions.  Alas!

Comment: @inappropriateCode this is really grey area. As I wrote,  I didn't vote. I considered voting, for the  reasons I stated above, but I decided I'm not sure.

Comment: Hmm.  Should constraints have the same legitimacy as capabilities?  Since that's what I was asking, if it was feasible or not.

Comment: Moved comment to an answer.