# Why was the question "Would naruto-running titan zombies be able to cause an extinction event?" put on-hold as too story-based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

[Would naruto-running titan zombies be able to cause an extinction event?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/163908/32097)

Now, this question saw a major rewrite on my part, for the sake of clarity, around that time. In essence, I'm asking if these creatures would stand a chance at destroying humanity in Europe in the 15th century with that beginner set.

It doesn't seem too story-based for me. The titan zombies are a "unique" monster type, however, you could say the same for the thousand and one permutations of classic monsters that were used to end the world.

I also don't mention the exact year, as I didn't want to calculate in situational advantages or disadvantages, that weren't consistent throughout the whole period.

If you ask me, situational factors (that are up to the writer's discretion) are the hallmark of a story-based question, something I purposefully got rid of. Could I help them win? Yes. Do I want to? No, that'd be cheating.

**Why was the question "Would naruto-running titan zombies be able to cause an extinction event?" put on-hold as too story-based?**

Also, aren't tidally-locked planets are like a plague in WB, not in a bad way, but I think there are less bread crumbs, I've eaten in my life, than tidally-locked questions on this site.

Answer (score 4):

Your world is already built. You're asking us how a scenario in your world will play out. That's clearly crossed the line into being story based. Removing situational factors like you say you have doesn't make the question not story based. It just makes it a too broad story based question.

A good rule of thumb is that if someone could write a book as an answer to a question it's not a good fit for this site. You're asking us to write novels.

Comment: I ask for the probability of it happening, not how it could happen.

Comment: To have a non VLQ answer to a question of percentage you would need to describe how the scenario is likely to play out. Being a pedant and saying you're "technically asking about the likelyhood", doesn't change what is needed to answer the question.

Comment: added this part to the question: *"Now, a win scenario would be a snowball effect. In the n.r.t.z-s' case that is being able to increase their numbers via killing the enemy. The question if that snowball could ever start rolling? Naturally, once they start coming they won't stop coming and they don't stop coming and they don't stop coming a..."*

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't understand why the query was closed for being story based. @Mephistopheles doesn't actually ask about "plot elements such as the actions of characters"; doesn't ask about the "back story of a character".

As per the referred why did my query get closed [link](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened), this particular falls under ***Capabilities of characters within a world and creation of groups of characters (like nations) are on-topic***.

**Rationale**: Asking "would they be able to" is the equivalent of "can they do", clearly about capabilities rather than desires or narrative actions.