# Reopen request - "plausible RPG-style tanking" question

Tags: discussion

[A question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/173549/how-could-a-warrior-hold-a-large-monstrous-animals-attention-i-e-plausible) I asked last week was closed for being too story-based.

Indeed, I had laid out a long, detailed tactical scenario. There was no plot or character content; it was all intended for context, clarity, and specificity. But I can see how it could have been interpreted as too much of a story/scenario. (My opening sentence had also mentioned that this was for a scene in a story I'm writing, which probably didn't help my case.)

So after reading the [relevant FAQ](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened), I removed the long tactical scenario entirely, then edited my question down to a bare-bones, zero-story, generalized situation with just the minimum context necessary to illustrate the concept in question.

Is the question still too story-based? If not, could it be reopened?

Comment: Have you at least voted to reopen your own query? As it stands, I think mine appears to be the only reopen vote. And that was because I read this as a tactics query, and thus on topic, rather than a plot element query, which of course is not!

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not seeing the reopen option. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423) is telling me I need more reputation. Maybe I'm missing something though.

Answer (score 1):

A first pass of your post in it's current state had me thinking you were still asking whether a group of individuals would be successful in a scenario. It was only after carefully reading your question while composing this post that it became clear to me that the actual text of your question was asking about something that could be considered worldbuilding. Unfortunately the edits made the question rather broad and dependent upon details that you had removed.

I would recommend doing a rework on your question to emphasize the importance of this question to the world you are building. For instance if you were asking about Neanderthals hunting mammoth you could have your post be structured something like:

> I'm writing a story in which a brave neanderthal hunter saves their tribe by distracting a ferocious mammoth allowing other hunters to get close enough to deliver the killing blow. I want to know if this seems plausible. Are there any examples of similar behavior in the real world I can use to flesh out my description?

This provides the essential context about the scenario but shows that your reason for the question is in fleshing out detains of your world rather than whether your hunter will be successful or not.

Comment: The "whether a group of individuals would be successful in a scenario" distinction is helpful, thanks. I revised the question so the conceptual meat of the question is up front.