# What happened to the idea generation close reason?

Tags: support, close-reasons

Why is the close reason "idea generation" gone? I have not heard really anything about the change, probably because I don't go on meta too often. Could someone point me to a post about it, or just tell me? I'm reasonably sure it has become the "too broad" close reason, and the very subjective close reason of plot based was added in its place.

Comment: See also that post from Monica: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2337/9685

Comment: We're working on defining more risk factors (that may or may not become their own close reasons) at the moment so expect to see more options in the list over the next few weeks and months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was too vague, so it got removed.

It's also misleading since basically everything we do here is idea generation of some sort.

Use "Too Broad" or "Primarily Opinion Based" as the alternatives.