# Can I ask others to create features for my world?

Tags: discussion

I was about to ask the question "what exotic states of matter would you create?" (state of matter as in gas, liquid, solid etc). I would give a couple of examples of exotic states of matter I created myself, so that the answerers could create things along the category.

However, the answers given in this manner would be almost entirely Original to their respective creators, and it may be considered intellectual theft to use their creations.

In general, would it be a problem to ask others to create parallel creations based on an example?

Comment: I believe everything on the SE falls under a creative commons license, so anyone can use it once it's out there. However, I think that question would be closed, either as _too broad_ or _primarily opinion-based_. We used to have an _idea generation_ close reason (this would fall under that), but it was deemed too unclear to users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*This answer formalizes and expands on my earlier comment, because I don't like seeing unanswered questions and no one else has answered yet.*

The Stack Exchange, as a whole, operates on a CC-BY-SA copyright model. As Tim mentions on [this other question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2187/6986) about the legality of re-using material found on the network, you should read the license to know what you can and cannot do (see the link in Tim's answer). However, in short, you can do whatever you want with the material from the site as long as say where you got the idea from and any changes you made to it.

That being said, the concept of a question requesting answers propose ideas for your world runs contrary to the purpose of the Worldbuilding SE. The community exists to provide solutions to problems you have, or to verify that what you have is consistent with the rest of your world. A question asking for the community to build parts of your world for you given an idea would probably be closed as either *too broad* or *primarily opinion-based*.

More accurately, this would fall under the [*idea generation*](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/522/6986) close-reason we used to have, [but got rid of](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3304/6986) because it was unclear for new users what it meant or how it applied.

Comment: The *user content* is licensed under CC-BY-SA. That doesn't mean that every way of using or expressing the *idea* thus expressed is. I would say it would be very much courteous to say where you got the idea from, but as long as you don't use the content of a Worldbuilding (or for that matter any Stack Exchange site) post *verbatim*, the license shouldn't be the limiting factor in what you can do.

Comment: If I have a problem to be solved, but need to ask what object could solve it, would that question be considered 'idea-generation'? For example, I need a very specific feature of my fantasy world which is high up and can be seen from anywhere on the planet, and can be man-made (with magic if necessary), *but is not higher than a ring the planet has*. It would be easy for me to tell which suggestion is best, which is one of the requirements Tim B mentions in the 'idea generation' link you gave. Would such a question be on topic? The question would be based on requirements, not an idea.

Comment: @ThomasMyron I see nothing wrong with that concept in general. If you want more specific feedback, you can post your question to the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4835/6986).