# Inactive Sandbox 2017-18

Tags: discussion, questions, sandbox

[In order to make the Sandbox easier to use](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3813/6507), a new Sandbox question will be posted when the old one becomes too full. **This Sandbox has been retired.** You can check [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions-2014-2017) for the full list of past and present Question Sandboxes.

## What is the Sandbox?

This ["Sandbox"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development)) is a place where Worldbuilding.SE users can get feedback on prospective questions they wish to [post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions). This is useful because writing a clear and fully specified question on the first try can be difficult. There is a much better chance of your question being well received if you post it in the Sandbox first.

**To post a question to the Sandbox:**
Post an answer to this post with the content of your proposed question. You can create as many answers as you have proposed questions, but it is recommended that you only work on one question at a time. The content of the post should be as close as possible to the format you would use when asking on the main site. If you would like, you may add a section at the bottom explaining what parts of the proposed question you are most worried about (See the [Sandbox FAQ](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/640/2685) for more information on suggested syntax).

**Once you have posted your proposed question,** users will be able to comment on it with feedback. You can then respond to their feedback with comments of your own, or make edits to your post to attempt to address their feedback (after editing, be sure to comment to notify the user that you have taken their advice). The feedback/edit cycle can go on for as long as needed until either you are confident that your question is ready to be asked on the main site, or you've decided the question just won't work.

**When you think your question is ready for the public**, go ahead and [post it to the main site](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To help keep this sandbox clean, you should edit your post here so that it contains the title and URL of the posted question, and nothing else. Regardless of whether or not you decided to post to the main site, **once you are done with your Sandbox post, you should delete it**. This will not completely delete the post, but it will get it out of the way so that new proposed questions can be more easily located.

**Keep the Sandbox clean.** In order to [keep the Sandbox clean](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/sandbox-cleanup) users are encouraged to [look out for questions that have not seen any activity in some time](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4912/28789). If you come across a question draft that has not seen any activity from the author in the form of edits to the draft and comments as responses to other peoples comments you should leave a comment. In the comment you should ask if the user is still working on the question draft and remind him that his post might be deleted in the future if there is no further activity. If you see a question draft that has not seen any activity for at least 30 days and that has had a comment asking if the author is still working on the question draft for at least a week you should flag the post for moderator attention and ask for deletion. This helps to keep the Sandbox clean in cases where the author has abandoned his question draft.

**Please avoid answering questions here.** I know it's tempting, but answering the question in a comment will clog the comments and make it harder to see good guidance. If you have an answer for the proposed question, simply wait for it to be posted to the main site, and answer it there.

**See the [Sandbox FAQ](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/639/2685) for more information on how to use the Sandbox.**

**Please make sure you wait at least a day after posting into the Sandbox to give a range of people time to see the question and respond.**

### The Sandbox works best if you sort posts by "active" (click [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835?answertab=active) to do so).

Comment: What should I do if I decide not to post the question at all. Just silently delete my post here?

Comment: @SK19 Yes, that should be sufficient. You may also want to add a small note to that effect to the top of the post, just to make it clear to later visitors why you deleted it.

Comment: I have some questions that graduated and can't share. Not sure how this app is suppose to work. Apologies for missing announcement to comment and graduate.

Comment: Do I need to do something special in the app?

Comment: @Jake If you have a graduated question you should shorten the draft to something like "Posted: <link>", then delete the draft and add the link to the [community wiki](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4858/28789).

Comment: @Secespitus Even if the question has been deleted?

Comment: @Jake The moment you post your question on main you should edit and delete your draft in the Sandbox. I can't remember anyone directly removing the quesiton once it was posted. Or are you talking about a question draft here in the Sandbox? "Graduation" normally refers to the act of posting a draft on main. If you deleted your draft because you don't want to continue working on it you should not add it to the community wiki, just shorten it. If you intend to work on it again at any point you can flag it for moderator attention and ask for undeletion or simply post a new draft.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In accordance with http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1728/sandbox-overflow, many answers containing now-graduated questions have been deleted. This is designed to be a repository for all those questions that have graduated. It is a community wiki answer, so add in your question here, at the end of the list once it is posted on the main site!

1. [When and how would a Dyson sphere civilization in a fantasy setting learn size and shape of the sphere?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/79425/when-and-how-would-a-dyson-sphere-civilization-in-a-fantasy-setting-learn-size-a)
2. [How do I make a server of a virtual world indestructible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/80545/how-do-i-make-a-server-of-a-virtual-world-indestructible)
3. [A post-apocalyptic industrial revolution](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/80746/a-post-apocalyptic-industrial-revolution)
4. [How can a state culturally reinforce the euthanization of deformed children?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/80787/how-can-a-state-culturally-reinforce-the-euthanization-of-deformed-children)
5. [What kinds of plants could grow in near crystals and in (mostly) crystal sands?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/80948/what-kinds-of-plants-could-grow-near-crystals-and-in-mostly-crystal-sands)
6. [Time Travel and random events](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/81214/time-travel-and-random-events)
7. [Would an avian-style jetpack be advantageous?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/82038/would-an-avian-style-jetpack-be-advantageous)
8. [Would creatures, evolved to tolerate the consequences of mouth breathing, gain more oxygen?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/82072/would-creatures-evolved-to-tolerate-the-consequences-of-mouth-breathing-gain-m)
9. [The Science behind X-COM: Plasma Rifles](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/82077/the-science-behind-x-com-plasma-rifles)
10. [How could I contain plasma for use in weapons?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/82202/32097)
11. [Mobile phone with tower independent long distance communication features](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/82196/mobile-phone-with-tower-independent-long-distance-communication-features)
12. [Economic systems for micronations in space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/83319/economic-systems-for-micronations-in-space)
13. [Ensuring an endless war, and an endless stalemate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/83902/ensuring-an-endless-war-and-an-endless-stalemate)
14. [Weapon design: a conceivable superheated sword capable of cutting through most things](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/86137/7974)
15. [Charged Particle Beam propagation in air](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/86934/charged-particle-beam-propagation-in-air)
16. [How to Explain Traits of Alicorn](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/87413/how-to-explain-traits-of-alicorn)
17. [Would introducing natural birth control early in human evolution limit genetic diversity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/87617/would-introducing-natural-birth-control-early-in-human-evolution-limit-genetic-d)
18. [How do I explain the formation of my world scientifically?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/87422/how-do-i-explain-the-formation-of-my-world-scientifically)
19. [How to quarantine an entire peninsula?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/88150/how-to-quarantine-an-entire-peninsula)
20. [Anatomically Correct Nachtkrapp](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/88204/28789)
21. [How to seize control of a region?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/88433/25770)
22. [How to institute "The Purge" in a society while still allowing it to function?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/89517/28789)
23. [How would the Greek call a wizard that can control life?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/89756/how-would-the-greek-call-a-wizard-that-can-control-life)
24. [Can a casino system prove my (divine) luck as cheating?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/90245/can-a-casino-system-prove-my-divine-luck-as-cheating)
25. [How would it affect a human to suddenly have a sense of smell comparable to a wolf?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/90456/how-would-it-affect-a-human-to-suddenly-have-a-sense-of-smell-comparable-to-a-wo)
26. [Possibility of a large as of yet undetected object headed to intercept our solar system](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/90489/possibility-of-a-large-as-of-yet-undetected-object-headed-to-intercept-our-solar)
27. [How can elemental magic aid forensic in a magical murder?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/90941/how-can-elemental-magic-aid-forensic-in-a-magical-murder)
28. [How plausible is a system of clans of pure-blood wizards?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/90984/how-plausible-is-a-system-of-clans-of-pure-blood-wizards)
29. [How would it affect a human to suddenly have the visual senses of a martial eagle?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/91230/how-would-it-affect-a-human-to-suddenly-have-the-visual-senses-of-a-martial-eagl)
30. [How can a reversible elemental magic damage be explained?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/91839/how-can-a-reversible-elemental-magic-damage-be-explained)
31. [How to Design Wind Instruments for a Race With Snouts](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/92048/how-to-design-wind-instruments-for-a-race-with-snouts)
32. [What could justify a save point before a boss fight in RPG?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/92170/what-could-justify-a-save-point-before-a-boss-fight-in-rpg)
33. [What kind of wing design would a quadruped with six wings need to fly well?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/93050/what-kind-of-wing-design-would-a-quadruped-with-six-wings-need-to-fly-well)
34. [How would a plant substitute light with magma to "photosynthesize"?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/93203/how-would-a-plant-substitute-light-with-magma-to-photosynthesize)
35. [How can a lava-eater metabolism explained?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/93205/how-can-a-lava-eater-metabolism-explained)
36. [Could these methods be used as an effective deterrent for sexual violence?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/93772/28789)
37. [How would one determine the upper and lower temperature limits for a race of human-sized reptiles?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/94033/how-would-one-determine-the-upper-and-lower-temperature-limits-for-a-race-of-hum)
38. [How much muscle mass would be needed for a genetically modified human to move his ~1 metre long foxtail?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/94777/how-much-muscle-mass-would-be-needed-for-a-genetically-modified-human-to-move-hi)
39. [How can a desert have high humidity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/94801/how-can-a-desert-have-high-humidity)
40. [Mental illness that spreads through social contact](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/94800/mental-illness-that-spreads-through-social-contact)
41. [How could one handle the chaotic energies used to produce a human demon hybrid?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/94781/how-could-one-handle-the-chaotic-energies-used-to-produce-a-human-demon-hybrid)
42. [What is the process of making a word become a taboo in a tribe?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/95343/what-is-the-process-of-making-a-word-become-a-taboo-in-a-tribe)
43. [How can a monarchy ensure the loyalty of royal factions in a clan-based system?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/95388/how-can-a-monarchy-ensure-the-loyalty-of-royal-factions-in-a-clan-based-system)
44. [Where can I look up information for creating a magic system based on Tarot?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/95480/where-can-i-look-up-information-for-creating-a-magic-system-based-on-tarot)
45. [In a culture that writes in cricles what would the medium for writing look like?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/95485/in-a-culture-that-writes-in-circles-what-would-the-medium-for-writing-look-like)
46. [How to ensure only one child survives out of many established embryos?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/95946/how-to-ensure-only-one-child-survives-out-of-many-established-embryos)
47. [How can I ensure that I don't miss something important to the functioning of society when building a government and set of statutes for my world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/95686/how-can-i-ensure-that-i-dont-miss-something-important-to-the-functioning-of-soc)
48. [Chemical weapon to kill a werewolf](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/96428/43337)
49. [How small can a population be with regard to genetic diversity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/98551/how-small-can-a-population-be-with-regard-to-genetic-diversity)
50. [Why would a modern country execute it's criminals only during a certain time of the year?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/98618/why-would-a-country-execute-criminals-only-at-a-certain-time-of-the-year)
51. [Earliest possible colony in the Americas?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/98605/earliest-possible-colony-in-the-americas)
52. [Is there a possibility for electricity to go through a computer screen?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/98912/28789)
53. [How would I calculate how much of Venus would be covered in water if 8.8E16 m^3 was added to its surface?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/99606/how-would-i-calculate-how-much-of-venus-would-be-covered-in-water-if-8-8e16-m3)
54. [How high can Ludicrous Leg man jump?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/99681/how-high-can-ludicrous-leg-man-jump)
55. [If the US launched air strikes against Cuba during the Cuban Missile Crisis, would any Soviet missile sites be able to survive?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/99703/if-the-us-launched-air-strikes-against-cuba-during-the-cuban-missile-crisis-wou)
56. [What could cause sugary rain?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/100275/what-could-cause-sugary-rain)
57. [Train-World: Feasibility of radioisotope steam-electric engines](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/101288/train-world-feasibility-of-radioisotope-steam-electric-engines)
58. [Could successfully fostering a working relationship with the U.S. government have protected the American mafia from RICO?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/101306/could-successfully-fostering-a-working-relationship-with-the-u-s-government-hav)
59. [Would the diet of a human have to adapt if he suddenly had a ~1 metre long foxtail?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/101414/would-the-diet-of-a-human-have-to-adapt-if-he-suddenly-had-a-1-metre-long-foxta)
60. [How broken would my jPhone be if I traveled back in time 24 hours?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/101485/how-broken-would-my-jphone-be-if-i-traveled-back-in-time-24-hours)
61. [How do you determine placement of multiple lunar bodies in the night sky?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/101690/how-do-you-determine-placement-of-multiple-lunar-bodies-in-the-night-sky)
62. [Can a lack of diseases in the medieval world lead to overpopulation?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/101876/can-a-lack-of-diseases-in-the-medieval-period-lead-to-overpopulation)
63. [Would the ability to determine the sex of your child result in an imbalanced ratio in a culture that favours girls?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/101952/would-the-ability-to-determine-the-sex-of-your-child-result-in-an-imbalanced-rat)
64. [How could I explain why a humanoid, intelligent creature melts when splashed with pure water?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/102225/28789)
65. [What would be different if a person has broader visual spectrum than normal](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/102346/7974)
66. [How to not hurt yourself with very sharp spikes on tail?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/102730/how-to-not-hurt-yourself-with-very-sharp-spikes-on-tail)
67. [How can I figure out the territorial needs for my Werewolves?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/103072/how-can-i-figure-out-the-territorial-needs-for-my-werewolves)
68. [How well will interstellar Ploughs work?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/103155/how-well-will-interstellar-ploughs-work)
69. [Great Old Ones Limited: Or Why Does C'Thulu Need A Company?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/104046/great-old-ones-limited-or-why-does-cthulu-need-a-company)
70. [How would having two pairs of vocal cords affect the voice of a humanoid?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/106141/how-would-having-two-pairs-of-vocal-cords-affect-the-voice-of-a-humanoid)
71. [Could soft matter infused with nano or pico sized magnets be used to clump together so that we could create environments with it?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/106061/could-soft-matter-infused-with-nano-or-pico-sized-magnets-be-used-to-clump-toget)
72. [How would having two pairs of vocal cords affect the voice of a humanoid?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/106141/how-would-having-two-pairs-of-vocal-cords-affect-the-voice-of-a-humanoid)
73. [How long lasts a second of eternity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/107053/how-long-lasts-a-second-of-eternity)
74. [What are the ley lines this nomadic people uses to follow the same path year after year?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/107347/what-are-the-ley-lines-this-nomadic-people-uses-to-follow-the-same-path-year-aft)
75. [What's the smallest change necessary to make Mutually Assured Destruction…not assured?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/107627/whats-the-smallest-change-necessary-to-make-mutually-assured-destruction-not)
76. [What weaknesses could someone exploit to manipulate this “Approval plus RCV” electoral system?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/107688/what-weaknesses-could-someone-exploit-to-manipulate-this-approval-plus-rcv-ele)
77. [Train-World: The shatterpated machinations of Spoorcaneers - Tossing & Turning](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/108021/train-world-the-shatterpated-machinations-of-spoorcaneers-tossing-turning)
78. [How to make the Earth red again?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/108715/28789)
79. [Egg Geometry--Shape of Eggs in Oviparous Humanoids](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110094/egg-geometry-shape-of-eggs-in-oviparous-humanoids)
80. [How to engineer hyper-coffee](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110149/how-to-engineer-hyper-cofee)
81. [How do genetically modified rodents cause the apocalypse?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110319/how-do-genetically-modified-rodents-cause-the-apocalypse)
82. [Simulating Cave Formations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110426/simulating-cave-formations)
83. [How can a colony of teleporters make the most money while keeping their teleporation a secret?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/111349/)
84. [Communication via Magical Sound](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/111516/communication-via-magical-sound)
85. [How to make an Earth with 27 suns work](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/111855/how-to-make-an-earth-with-27-suns-work)