# Cold-hearted closing of this ice question makes me shiver

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopening-questions

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/83418/how-to-make-ice-magic-possible) about how to reshape ice in my world was closed as too broad.

However, I don't understand what it lacked in its edited version, where I specified *how* my world worked, *what* I wanted, and *up to where* I had found answers. I thought I had edited accordingly to all the feedback I had received...

What should I add ?

Comment: Do you see a “reopen” grey link under the tags?  Yse that to submit to the review queue again.

Comment: I see it was closed 4 hours *after* your last edit.  So people were still thinking it’s too broad.

Comment: Yes, so it seems

Comment: In any case, it already has an Accepted answer!  So why are yiu worried about it remaining open?

Comment: Well, I guess it means it's a bad question, so...

Comment: @NathanCoustenoble Just a tip for the future if you are worried about whether something you want to post is a bad question or not: we have a [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on Meta that is specifically to help people get feedback on that general stuff before releasing it onto the Main Site. And it's good if you want to improve your style by asking for the reasons and feedback here on Meta.

Comment: Oh you're right thank you

Comment: Love your title for this question.

Comment: ......      ;)        .......