# Is asking whether some strategy already exists on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Say I have some strategy that I want to add to my game (it could be a RTS or other kind of strategy game), is it ok to ask whether there is something similar to that already in some other game, or even in real life, if we talk about strategies and tactics used in real world conflicts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you want to ask about *game* design more than *world* design.  That would be off-topic here, but you might want to take a look at [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

If your question is more about the world itself -- and military tactics are generally on-topic here if they more systemic and less plot-specific -- then it's better to ask about *the problem you're trying to solve*, rather than asking *who else might have solved it*.  Answers can then point to that prior art if relevant.  Consider the difference between

> How can a medieval-tech army defend itself against dragons with arrow-resistant hides?

and

> What games have solved the arrows-against-dragons problem?

Comment: Let's say I have something in place (for instance three types of units where the attack, defense, and range points are balanced so no unit can work alone), and I want someone to say, "that's scissor paper stone", would that be ok?

Comment: Oh, you mean asking about *identifying* a strategy?  I don't know if we've had these types of questions before, so I don't know how the community would handle them.  The [question sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4835/28) might be a good way to test the waters and get feedback before people start voting on main.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks.

Comment: @rraallvv It seems like you're wanting to know about game mechanics and if the terms for particular mechanics of strategy games have names. This seems like a question better suited for Game Development than here as Monica said.