# is the question narrow enough to put on the main site?

Tags: discussion

[Could the biological capability to control their reproductive process justify a matriarchal society forming?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69568/could-the-biological-capability-to-control-their-reproductive-process-justify-a)

I had asked this question some time ago. The current premise is similar, but without the fantastical elements such as magic and demons. In this scenario, women have the innate birth control and the ability to control their reproductive functions. This ability developed early in human history and has helped lead to a matriarchal system developing. Pregnancy is an active process, and gestation rate can be controlled or pause to some limited extent. All drawbacks from pregnancy have been removed, such as morning sickness, cramps, etc. birth is a relatively painless process, which can be held off until the mother is ready in a convenient time.

The question is: would taking the randomness out of human reproduction by adding  limit genetic diversity. If a natural form of birth control was present early in evolution, would it lead to homogeneity in the human species?

Comment: (Not really a duplicate, but you should use the sandbox for this.)

Answer (score 3):

We'd need to see exactly what you intend to ask to really be able to weigh in on whether your question is too broad or not. Luckily we have [the sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) for situations like this.

It looks like your question could benefit from some edits for clarity. Why don't you post it to the sandbox and get some feedback on it.