# Etiquette around deleting questions

Tags: discussion

I've asked a question that doesn't actually ask for the information I'm interested in but people are interacting with it anyway and seem interested enough in the question as it is. I guess what I'm asking is what's the etiquette around deleting a question that in hindsight is

1. Stupid because I already have a number of answers *and*
2. Doesn't actually ask about what I'm aiming at *but*
3. Does seem to interest others?

Answer (score 4):

## Please do not delete such a question

If a question is well-received and gets answers that generate upvotes it is normally a good idea to leave the question. People spent time researching this topic and collecting information. Even if you are not that interested in the topic anymore because you feel you didn't specify clearly what you wanted, someone else might later be interested in the topic.

SE aims at providing information for users who later come and need answers to their questions. It's good that you help build up this database.

## Ask a new question

You can just ask a new question with what you really want to know. This will expand the database, give you and others reputation and doesn't do any harm in any way. If you want someone else to have a look before you post it to make sure it won't be viewed as a duplicate and is clear this time I recommend giving the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) a try.

## Addendum

You mentioned that you already have a number of answers - SE encourages users to post questions and answer them yourself. If you feel someone would profit from your research and you would like to help others in a similar situation you might well post such a self-answered question in the future.