# Which takes precedence - the absolute value of the speed of light or Heisenberg’s uncertainty principle?

Tags: discussion, sandbox

#### Which takes precedence - the absolute value of the speed of light or Heisenberg’s uncertainty principle?

What is the relationship between the absolute nature of the speed of light and the indeterminate nature of Heisenberg’s uncertainty principle?

If an object is moving at speeds close to the speed of light, does the uncertainty principle impose any “fuzziness” on the consistency of the speed of light? Or does the speed of light impose any restrictions on the uncertainty principle?

I find it hard to describe the question well, but I think it boils down to this: can any of an object’s many superpositions involve faster than light travel?

---

Is this sufficiently clear and is it sufficiently on topic?

Comment: You should use our [question sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4835/29) for this. I see it had been automatically protected, which happens from time to time; I have unprotected it. If it gets protected again, just flag it and a mod will unprotect it in short order.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Slarty*! I formatted your draft a bit. It would be nice if you could take it to the Sandbox post and post it there as an answer. The Sandbox is the normal way to work on a question draft. What tags do you want to use for this question? [tag:science-fiction] [tag:science-based] [tag:faster-than-light] could be appropriate. You can write tags into your draft like so: `[tag:science-based]` Currently your complete draft consists of questions when looking at the amount of question marks. It would be good to rephrase that to use normal sentences and only one question at end

Comment: I thought I had used the question sand box. The sand box does not appear that easy for new users to find as there is no direct link to it from the main menu (correct me if I'm wrong). If this question has been answered I would also be interested to know what the answer was. Following the link leads to a lot of questions none of which appears to be that one, unless its buried somewhere...

Comment: Thanks. I will try again later with some tags and a different format.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling marked this as a duplicate to our Sandbox post. If you follow the link in the upper part of your question you come to our [Sandbox for Proposed Questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions). It's basically a question post and all drafts should be written as an answer to that post. You wrote a new question on our Meta Site. This site is used to talk about Meta topics of WorldBuilding.StackExchange, like how to use your privileges, which tags to use, ... I don't think your question has been answered on the Main Site so far