# Do we need the tag [transformation]?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

In a different discussion [@EveryBitHelps wondered](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5982/how-to-rewrite-a-controversial-question-when-i-didnt-get-the-answers-i-was-expe#comment17724_5984) whether [transformation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformation) would be a good tag to add to a question, which made me realize that this tag exists.

The tag has neither a tag wiki excerpt nor a full tag wiki. There are only two questions, one of them which is closed. Both seem to be about a sort of "magical" transformation:

- [I have been drinking a potion to stop a transformation. One day, I stopped drinking the potion. How would the transformation take place?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/91948/i-have-been-drinking-a-potion-to-stop-a-transformation-one-day-i-stopped-drink) is asking about a dragon-human hybrid that stops taking some kind of hormone suppressor and wonders how the *transformation* to the original half-dragon would look like
- [Adjusting from Quadruped to Biped](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/97214/28789) wonders about how a creature would adapt that was suddenly *transformed* from having four legs to only having two legs

To me it looks like both questions could just as well do without the tag or maybe with the [shapeshifters](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shapeshifters) tag. The idea behind the tag seems to be similar to that of [shapeshifters](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shapeshifters). The *transformations* seem to be involuntarily, but the [shapeshifters](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shapeshifters) tag already includes this (emphasis mine):

> Shape-shifters can completely change their body form. There tend to be 2 kinds:
>
> Sci-fi shape-shifters tend to keep the same mass and similar size, along the line of advanced octopuses.
>      Fantasy shifters have fewer restraints. Were-wolves are a common example: shifting from 80-pound wolf to 180-pound human to 300+-pound werewolf.
>
> **The transformations may be voluntary or involuntary.**
>
> This tag is for questions related to the feasibility and capabilities of these beings.

**Do we need the tag [transformation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformation) or do we want to burninate it?**

Comment: I added a few words to the [tag:shapeshifters] tag wiki excerpt to emphasize the fact that it allows for voluntary and involuntary shapeshifting alike.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks, that makes it a lot easier to see that [tag:shapeshifters] could be used in such circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there was no negative feedback on this question (+4/-0 as of writing this) and [@MichaelKjörling updated the shapeshifters tag wiki excerpt](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5985/do-we-need-the-tag-transformation#comment17730_5985) I've gone ahead and changed the [transformation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformation) tag to [shapeshifters](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shapeshifters) on the two mentioned questions.