# What to do when you receive unsatisfactory answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

After waiting and receiving unsatisfactory answers (because everyone is misunderstanding what you're saying, even if you restate the important part several times) and not counting adding a bounty, what are solutions to finding a satisfactory answer? And what about stopping the flow of unsatisfactory ones that unfortunately get upvotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a [Sandbox on Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) that can be used as a little testing ground to see how questions will be received and to root out potential problems. You could for example try to write up a new draft and add a few sentences for the Sandbox about what you were looking for in an answer to your original question. The people there can then help you with the wording and to make sure that your new question won't be viewed as a duplicate.

You already excluded bounties, but they are a normal way to give more attention to a question and to reward certain answers.

There isn't really any way to "stop the flow" of unsatisfactory answers. If your question is valid and the answers are valid then they will keep rolling in. Theoretically the question could be closed by a moderator (or enough community members), but the goal of SE is to have a database of questions and answers for future readers, so closing valid questions is not really in line with what the site is supposed to do. I would recommend against this approach. Just accept that this was a failed attempt at getting the answers you want.

But make sure that the answer are really valid. If they do not answer the question as it's posed you can downvote them, leave a comment explaining what is missing and then flag the answers as "not an answer". The comment is essential here, as other people seem to have already thought the answers are good and the reviewers should see that you as the OP see problems with them.

Just for completeness: please don't edit your existing question in a way that would invalidate existing answers. It sometimes happens that you don't quite get across what you were hoping. But if an edit would invalidate an answer then a new question based on that edit idea would surely not be viewed as a duplicate - the answers to one wouldn't be applicable to the other question after all.

Comment: Adding to the final paragraph, include a note highlighting the differences somehow. That way, even if the questions might appear superficially similar, there's something that points out the differences, greatly reducing the risk of them being considered duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

[Answer by Secespitus](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6017/809) is good. I just write mine to show it in as simple way as possible.

https://xkcd.com/1028/

> Anyone who says that they're great at communicating but 'people are bad at listening' is confused about how communication works.

If people do not understand you and that causes answers to be unsatisfactory to you, **do not repeat** important facts. Clearly, this is pointless, and you already seem to see that.

What you need to do, is to **find another way to ask**, one that will be easier to understand.