# Risk Factor Definition: Too Vague

Tags: discussion, on-topic

One of the next most popular Risk Factor suggestions is Too Vague so this is a general discussion of that close reason.

The main point to clarify is:

1. Should questions be off topic for this reason
2. If so should it be a close reason or a "canned comment".
3. We could do with some examples, we also need to work on the "how to fix" etc.

**Risk Factor: Too Vague**

Close Reason:

> You are asking about a world where not enough detail is available to give a specific answer.

Full Description:

> This covers questions where the question itself is clear and on topic but not enough detail has been given. For example a lot of magic questions are asked that fail to define the magic system well enough. As a result the answers can either be "a wizard did it" or have far too many possibilities to evaluate.

How to Fix:

> There are two common scenarios here.
>
> In science based questions -insert howto here-
>
> In magic or fantastical based questions -insert howto here-

Examples:

None so far - add some

Discussion points so far:

- I'd lean towards re-wording this as something like 'Your question needs to provide more details in order to get a specific answer,' since, for many questions, not a whole lot of detail is necessarily required. For something like the unicorn charge question, or the question about how dwarves would build cities, details about the world the dwarves/unicorns live on aren't strictly necessary, since we don't need them to have a good idea of what unicorns or dwarves are like.
- Is this an **off-topic** reason or is it a variant on "unclear what you are asking". If the latter then it should most likely be a canned comment.

Comment: I see this as a subset of 'too broad' whereas 'unclear what you are asking' I see as any question that has no question. Though I don't know if 'too vague' is any less vague than 'too broad' is broad.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Yes, "too broad" is for the cases where "I can tell what you are asking, and it's just too much" whereas "unclear what you are asking" is for the cases where "I can't even tell what you are asking".