# Is there anything wrong with low reputation users doing reviews?

Tags: discussion, reviews

I really enjoy doing reviews. It provides me with the ability to help other users get started on the site, and to improve the overall quality of the network. I take my time when reviewing posts and do so to the best of my knowledge and belief.

I feel like I am doing a good job, afterall I currently stand at 100% helpful flags and 100% accepted edits. I have read the [Scope clarification discussions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3263/scope-clarification-discussions) and the [rules of peer moderation](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3366/rules-of-peer-moderation). I also enjoy the experience of about 3k reviews on StackOverflow.

I do reviews in all queues I am allowed on, which currently are the late answers and first posts.

But what troubles me is the following:
WB does not have many posts that need to be reviewed (which is a good thing). Because of that, after performing some reviews I am currently within the top reviewers in the queues I have access to. So far nothing bad, but all the other reviewers appearing stand at multiple k reputation whereas I do not have that much, as I haven't answered that many questions yet. I feel a little bit like an underdog between all those "gleaming stars of the community" and am wondering, whether I belong there.

**Are there any reasons, that I should not do reviewing on Worldbuilding? Is there anything I can/ have to improve in?**

The only thing I could think of, is that one could argue that due to missing editing or close-voting rights, my flagging or suggesting edits generates additional work - but I feel like this is outweighted by the workload I handle doing the reviews that do not need a second pair of eyes.

I guess that many low-reputation users are more interested in getting their questions answered or do not know/ care about doing reviews. But I certainly do enjoy this part of StackExchange.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I'm not too far up on the ladder myself ;)

Comment: At first, I saw reputation as one of the most important things on this site. Then After I hit a couple thousand and it started to top out, I realized reputation doesn't matter too much. There are people who've been on this site since beta, and they have less than five hundred. It just depends on how familiar you are with the workings of the site. Also, where does your name come from?

Comment: @XandarTheZenon Yes, I also think that experience with the site and how you act on it are more important - however, in the lower reputation regions some privileges may be missing, like close voting for example or editing without the edit being peer reviewed. And the name is derived from my real name, which starts with *Tho*. I am german, so saying each letter out loud by itself results in *Te* - *ha* - *o* (Te Hao). Add some fancy 1337-Speak to it, and voila! This has been my online/gaming name/pseudonym for years and I like it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have to some extend the same feeling as you. If not here, then on other site.

IMO, everyone should enjoy the rights they are given. So do vote and flag, and edit. The main idea is to dedicate some of your time to improve the site, by hosting great questions, and making sure those get the best answers. If you're willing to contribute to that, then great. We thank you for it.

It is good that you have read all those posts. Feel free to contribute to the debate yourself. Knowing that you have taken the time to be familiar with the site, the idea, etc. Then I see no reason for you to stop or change.

You should note, however, that when we get to the full graduation, the threshold for close-votes will rise a bit. So to continue on that you'll need to gather a bit more of reputation. But that won't take your rights to up/down vote, flag or suggest some edition.

Comment: Thank you, this pretty much sums up how I feel about it. However, I will wait a little while before accepting to see if others have any other points.

Comment: I agree with this.  If you have access to the review queues it's because you're trusted to review, and you're obviously being conscientious about it.  If you see something in a queue that you're not sure how to handle (it needs an edit but you don't feel you can make it, for example), remember that there's a "skip" button.  Otherwise, if you take the action that needs to be taken, who cares if you don't have as much rep as somebody else who would have taken the same action?  We appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

It's great that you're so involved with Worldbuilding!

I go through the same thing on the sites which I have just joined. It's tough going from 10K+ rep to 100 (because we *trust you on other sites*). That feeling of starting over is daunting, for sure.

***However, it serves its purpose.***

Unlike you, a lot of people do not bother reading the scope clarification discussions, or the rules of peer moderation.

We've had quite an influx of new members lately, and we've also had a pretty major spike of questions put on hold precisely because those people did not educate themselves prior to posting. Some of those users simply dropped off the grid when their questions weren't well received, or lashed out in the comments rather than trying to understand how to improve their questions/answers.

I wouldn't want people such as those having more privileges simply because they created an account.

I, for one, have had users edit my answers to basically chew me out because they didn't agree with my opinion, or censor my posts for ideological reasons. I'm sure they were dealt with by the moderators, but they outline the sort of abuse of power that some people are capable of.

And so, I'm a fan of the current reputation thresholds. A user who commits abuses, does not educate themselves about the rules and scope of the site, or vandalizes people's posts will not last before being banned, or simply quitting, and will never gain the rep necessary to do even *more damage* by editing tags, etc.

Seeing a high rep user offer a review or opinion on SE is reassuring because you know for a fact that that person has gained the rep and privileges the *hard* way. By participating. Getting involved, and working within the framework of the site.

In your particular case, simply stick with it! I only joined the site 4 months ago, and I already have 10K reputation. Your dedication and effort will be rewarded in our unique SE way!

Comment: Thank you for all the motivation - all of you! I absolutely agree with the way, priviledges are granted on SE. It just felt weird to see myself there between all the heavy weight users. But I now feel reassured in my hopes, that what I do is well recieved and apreciated by the community. I am going to accept bilbo_pingouin's answer, simply because it is more focused on reviewing (my initial topic), as opposed to the reputation system that your answer focuses on.

Comment: Perhaps (for users with some mod privileges (from rep, mod status, etc) on several other sites) the "because we trust you on another site" could be bumped into some bigger starter rep "because we trust you a lot on several other sites". But again, someone that climbed the ropes that much on other SE sites would have no trouble knowing what should be done to get up on a new one.

Comment: @Mindwin - I'm against bumping people up on one site in order to reflect their reputation on some other SE site because there may be no overlap. Just because i give good advice on workplace doesn't mean I'm a top performer on history. If I was given privileges on History that I didn't earn the good ol' fashioned way SE would be spitting in the metaphorical eye of those users who did.

Comment: **"SE reputation"** is different from **"ability to give good advice"**, even though its blurry in the middle. People push them to be equal because of status quo and bragging rights (totally avoiding discussing if that is right, here). - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  But the closing line on my comment above should be reinforced: someone that reached high rep in several SE sites should have no problem building up rep in a new site.

Comment: But sometimes the goold ol' way needs to be challenged and possibly reviewed to adapt to new times, or we will never be able to marry our robotic cyborg partners in the future.

Comment: @Mindwin - didn't mean to offend anyone's robotic cyborg partner :-P